# Freelancing in Canada without work permit

Tags: canada, france, freelance

I am a EU citizen and I expect to visit Canada for an extended period (I am allowed to stay up to 6 months without a work permit).

As this is a rather long period, I would like to do some freelancing to finance it. Am I allowed to do so, declaring my income either in Canada (I honestly doubt of that) or in EU.

Does Canada allow this situation? what about France (as the EU country)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Canada (like most countries) doesn't generally allow "working in Canada" for visitors (tourists).  In other words, you're not allowed to work in the local job market, whether temporary or permanent.

Some types of remote work, for a non-Canadian employer, are possible, as you're then not directly competing in the local job market.

If you qualify, there are working holiday visas for young people ([International Experience Canada](http://www.international.gc.ca/experience/intro_incoming-intro_entrant.aspx)).  This is the best way to legally work in Canada for a short term.

Comment: According to the TV show Canada Border Security from National Geographic, there are a few occupations that do not require a work permit (street music performance comes to mind).

Answer (score 3):

If you are freelancing remotely to a company outside of Canada while employed by a company in the EU then you are definitely not working in Canada.

Here's what the Immigration, Refugees and Citizenship Canada says about [What kind of activities are not considered to be “work”?](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/resources/tools/temp/work/about.asp):

> long distance (by telephone or internet) work done by a temporary resident whose employer is outside Canada and who is remunerated from outside Canada;

Comment: Hi, do you have any reference to back that up, even some experience?

Comment: I haven't been doing that in Canada but I have been doing it in USA, Spain, Germany and Israel. Note: I haven't been in either of the countries for more than three months.

Comment: @Vince sure. Added.